# What is the difference between "probability density function" and "probability distribution function"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology, density-function

Whats the difference between *probability density function* and *probability distribution function*?

Comment: The density (when it exists) is the derivative of the distribution function.

Comment: You mean, "Difference between Probability density function and cumulative distribution function?"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concept of Probability distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57027/concept-of-probability-distribution)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The relation between the probability density funtion $f$ and the cumulative distribution function $F$ is...

- if $f$ is discrete:
  $$
  F(k) = \sum_{i \le k} f(i)
  $$
- if $f$ is continuous:
  $$
  F(x) = \int_{y \le x} f(y)\,dy
  $$

Comment: what is meant by discrete and continuous?

Comment: @maximus if the variable ranges over a discrete or continuous set of values. So if you're rolling a die, you have $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which is discrete. If you're picking a random point on a line, then your set is, say, the interval $[0,L]$ which is continuous.

Comment: @maximus For example, when flipping a coin or rolling a dice the outcome is discrete whereas measuring the time until the bus arrives at a bus stop is continuous.

Comment: so discrete is when you can count it! and continuous is when there is much more probability in it? Is this description right or wrong? Pls correct me!

Comment: @maximus That's correct though you may have to count forever. Check out the concept of a countable set for an exact definition.

Answer (score 44):

**Distribution Function**

1. The probability distribution function / probability function has ambiguous definition. They may be referred to:

   - Probability density function (PDF)
   - Cumulative distribution function (CDF)
   - or probability mass function (PMF) (statement from Wikipedia)
2. But what confirm is:

   - Discrete case: Probability Mass Function (PMF)
   - Continuous case: Probability Density Function (PDF)
   - Both cases: Cumulative distribution function (CDF)
3. Probability at certain $x$ value, $P(X = x)$ can be directly obtained in:

   - PMF for discrete case
   - PDF for continuous case
4. Probability for values less than $x$, $P(X < x)$ or Probability for values within a range from $a$ to $b$, $P(a < X < b)$ can be directly obtained in:

   - CDF for both discrete / continuous case
5. Distribution function is referred to CDF or Cumulative Frequency Function (see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistributionFunction.html))

**In terms of Acquisition and Plot Generation Method**

1. Collected data appear as discrete when:

   - The measurement of a subject is naturally discrete type, such as numbers resulted from dice rolled, count of people.
   - The measurement is digitized machine data, which has no intermediate values between quantized levels due to sampling process.
   - In later case, when resolution higher, the measurement is closer to analog/continuous signal/variable.
2. Way of generate a PMF from discrete data:

   - Plot a histogram of the data for all the $x$'s, the $y$-axis is the frequency or quantity at every $x$.
   - Scale the $y$-axis by dividing with total number of data collected (data size) $\longrightarrow$ and this is called PMF.
3. Way of generate a PDF from discrete / continuous data:

   - Find a continuous equation that models the collected data, let say normal distribution equation.
   - Calculate the parameters required in the equation from the collected data. For example, parameters for normal distribution equation are mean and standard deviation. Calculate them from collected data.
   - Based on the parameters, plot the equation with continuous $x$-value $\longrightarrow$ that is called PDF.
4. How to generate a CDF:

   - In discrete case, CDF accumulates the $y$ values in PMF at each discrete $x$ and less than $x$. Repeat this for every $x$. The final plot is a monotonically increasing until $1$ in the last $x$ $\longrightarrow$ this is called discrete CDF.
   - In continuous case, integrate PDF over $x$; the result is a continuous CDF.

**Why PMF, PDF and CDF?**

1. PMF is preferred when

   - Probability at every $x$ value is interest of study. This makes sense when studying a discrete data - such as we interest to probability of getting certain number from a dice roll.
2. PDF is preferred when

   - We wish to model a collected data with a continuous function, by using few parameters such as mean to speculate the population distribution.
3. CDF is preferred when

   - Cumulative probability in a range is point of interest.
   - Especially in the case of continuous data, CDF much makes sense than PDF - e.g., probability of students' height less than $170$ cm (CDF) is much informative than the probability at exact $170$ cm (PDF).

Comment: Note that the probability at P(X=x) cannot be obtained in the continuous case by evaluating the density function at x. Rather you can obtain it by integrating the density function from x to x, which will return 0. This is because the probability of observing any particular value in a continuous distribution is 0.

Answer (score -1):

Some abuse of language exists in these terms, which can vary. Below is a common usage.

In the continuous case (**density**):

```
(continuous) probability distribution function = probability density function = density function
(continuous) probability distribution = density
```

In the discrete case (**mass/distribution**):

```
(discrete) probability distribution function = probability mass function
(discrete) probability distribution = distribution
```

Oddly enough, you may never see a `probability mass function` called a `mass function` or a `distribution function`, nor may you see a `discrete probability distribution` called a `mass`. I am sure there is some historical reason as to why. As they say, *das war schon immer so und wird auch immer so bleiben*.