# What is the difference between a density and a distribution in formal mathematical terms?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

A similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175850/168764) has been already asked but its not in mathematical framework and therefore seems to be different. According to definitions from the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000472) that I am reading, a *random variable* and a *distribution* are defined as follows:

> **Definition.** Let $(\Omega', \mathcal{A}')$ be a measurable space and let $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ be measurable. Then $X$ is called a *random variable*.
>
> **Definition.** Let $X$ be a random variable. The probability measure $P_X:=P\circ X^{-1}$ is called the *distribution*.

Now according to what I see in physical textbooks there is some other thing called density and that differs from distribution. How that one is formally defined?

Comment: Short answer: a probability density, when it exists, is the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative) of its corresponding distribution.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, Thank you. It would have been great if you have written this as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The distribution is simply the assignment of probabilities to sets of possible values of the random variable.  If I tell you how probable it is that a certain random variable is between $3$ and $5$, and also how probably it is that it's in every other possible set, then I've told you the **distribution**.  Since I can't do this for every set individually, since there are infinitely many sets, perhaps a more down-to-earth way to say this is this: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.  If it is true of every set that the probability that $X$ is in that set is the same as the probability that $Y$ is in that same set, then $X$ and $Y$ have the **same distribution**.

A probability density function is a way of characterizing some distributions.  For example, consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x<0, \\ e^{-x} & \text{if }x\ge 0. \end{cases}
$$
To say that this is the probability density function of a random variable $X$ is to say that for every measurable set $A$ of real numbers,
$$
\Pr(X\in A) = \int_A f(x)\,dx.
$$
The probability assigned to each set $A$ is given by the integral above.  A more concrete example:
$$
\Pr(3<X<5) = \int_3^5 e^{-x}\,dx\text{ and }\Pr(X\ge 2) = \int_2^\infty e^{-x}\,dx.
$$

Not every probability distribution has a density.  Say we let $X$ be the number of aces when a die is thrown four times.  Then $X\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  The probability distribution assigns a positive number to every set that intersects that last set.  For example the set $\{x : x\ge 3.2\}$ intersects $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and thus the probability distribution of $X$ assigns a positive number to that set.  But there is no function $f$ such that for every set $A$ we have $\int_A f(x)\,dx$ equal to the probability that $X\in A$.

**PS prompted by comments below:** To put it in a different kind of language: Say $m$ is a measure (not necessarily assigning finite measure to the whole space) on the set of all measurable subsets of a space $S$.  A probability density with respect to the measure $m$ is a measurable function $f:S\to[0,\infty)$ such that the function
$$
A\mapsto \int_A f\,dm
$$
is a probability measure on the set of measurable subsets of $S$.

A probability distribution on $S$ is simply a probability measure on the set of all measurable subsets of $S$.  But not quite "simply": The probability distribution **of a random variable $X:\Omega\to S$** is the probability measure on measurable subsets of $S$ that assigns measure $P(\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\in A\})$ to each measurable subset $A$ of $S$.

**PPS:** When $f\ge0$ is a measurable function on Borel or Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$, one sometimes refers to the "measure" $f(x)\,dx$, meaning the measure
$$
A\mapsto \int_A f(x)\,dx.
$$
If in addition $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\,dx=1$, so that $f$ is a probability density, then one may similarly refer to the "probability distribution" $f(x)\,dx$.

(Of course, not all probability distributions on Borel subsets of the real line are of this form.)

Comment: I appreciate the time you have spent on answering the question with such a detailed answer but I was looking for the formal definition. One more thing is what you have defined again(distributions) has been already defined as part of my question.

Comment: @Cupitor : I've now added a "formal" definition.

Comment: @O.B.D.A. : Typo fixed.

Comment: You say that $X$ and $Y$ are r.v.s (which are functions), and then you talk about r.v.s that belong to a set, which is a little bit confusing, even though you can have sets of functions. I don't think that you're referring to functions when you say that  "If it is true of every set that the probability that $X$ is in that set". Maybe you are referring to the codomain of the $X$?

Comment: @nbro : In conventional usage in probability theory, the probability that a random variable $X$ is in a set $A$ is $P(X\in A) = P\{ \omega\in\Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}.$ It does not mean the probability that the function $X$ as a whole is a member of the set $A. \qquad$