# Generating probability distribution function from continuous data

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

We have a continuous function $F(x,y)$ defined on a bounded domain $(x, y) \in [0, L_x] \times [0, L_y]$. Suppose the function $F$ (the explicit form is irrelevant here) is defined such that $F(x,y)$ always lies between, say, 0 and 1.

By varying $x$ and $y$ continuously over the finite region, we obtain a set of corresponding (continuous) values for $F$. Now, I would like to find the PDF of the values assumed by $F$ itself. In other words, what I am looking for is the probability $P\, [F = \zeta;\,\, 0 \le \zeta \le 1]$ as a function of $\zeta$ .

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/697467) suggests a numerical prescription for such a situation as follows:

> Way of generate a PDF from discrete / continuous data:
>
> - Find a continuous equation that models the collected data, let say normal distribution equation
> - Calculate the parameters required in the equation from the collected data.For example, parameters for normal distribution equation are mean and standard deviation. Calculate them from collected data
> - Based on the parameters, plot the equation with continuous x-value --> that is called PDF

However, I was wondering if there is a method to obtain the PDF analytically, given that we know the exact functional form of $F$.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this regard. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you have a pair of continuous random variable $(X, Y)$ with support $[0, L_x]\times[0,L_y]$ and want to find out the distribution of $F(X, Y)$ ?

Comment: I guess we can probably view it that way with X and Y having a uniform distribution on the support.

Comment: Is F, by any chance,  the joint CDF of X and Y?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza No, tried that already. I think OP means they have some function, call it $h(x,y)$. OP calls it $F(x,y)$ but I mistook it for the CDF since that is the convention. I think what OP wants is something like $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{P(X\in dx, Y\in dy)}{dx\,dy}$, where $P(X\in dx, Y\in dy)$ is to be determined using $h(x,y)$. It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

$F(x,y) = \zeta \Longrightarrow P(X<x, Y<y) = \zeta.$

If you want the joint pdf, you take
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\,\partial y}F(x,y) = f(x,y),$$
if I understand your question correctly.

---

Allow me to try again.

After some thought, I realized that it might be the case that what you call $F(x,y)$ is something I would call $h(x,y)$. $F(x,y)$ is generally understood to mean the joint CDF. I think then that to get the joint pdf, you want $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{P(X\in dx, Y\in dy)}{dx\,dy},$$ where $P(X\in dx, Y\in dy)$ is to be determined using $h(x,y)$.

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding. What I am looking for is the distribution function of $\xi$, where the variable $\xi$ takes all possible values of F in the permitted region.

Comment: @CuriousStudent I might be misunderstanding. There are a number of things that confuse me. 1. Are you saying that $F$ corresponds to $\xi$. If so, then the pdf of $\xi$ is still $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\,\partial y}F(x,y)$. 2. $0\leq F(x,y) \leq 1$ always. So you are saying that the range of $\xi$ is $(0,1)$?

Comment: 1. Yes. Just to be clear, consider a concrete case. Say, x = 0.2, y = 0.8. Then F (0.2, 0.8) is one possible value of $\xi$. Similarly, all other values of x and y yield the other values of $\xi$. Of course, I have chosen a discrete example for clarity but x and y are actually continuous. 2. Yes, the range is (0,1), in this case. However, what if, more generally, it is any interval?

Comment: @CuriousStudent Ok, I think I understand what you are asking, and I think I can't respond. I'm curious to see the result.

Comment: @CuriousStudent I tried again.

Answer (score 0):

General method to find pdf: 1) find cdf, 2) take derivative...

e.g. we can do this for the standard normal.  Let:

$N$ = pdf for standard normal

$N^{-1}$ = the inverse of the standard normal on $(0,\infty)$

Then:

$P(N(x) < y) = P(x<-N^{-1}(y)) + P(x>N^{-1}(y))$

This second probability is easy to compute, if we know the distribution for $x$.  E.g. if we choose an $x$ uniform on [0,1] and ask about the distribution of N(x):

$P(x>N^{-1}(y)) = 0$ if $y < N(1)$ or $y > N(0)$

$P(x>N^{-1}(y)) = N^{-1}(y)$ else

so $pdf(N) = \frac{d}{dy} N^{-1}(y)$

there's no simple formula, really... More examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: Tried that already, that's not what they wanted unfortunately. It's not clear.

Comment: This is the pdf of some function of X, which I think is what you are asking. Should be generalizable to multiple variables...